# In SQL, how can I give one matching column precedence over another?

Tags: sql, match, where-clause, operator-precedence

I've tried a few things, but I'm drawing a blank. Here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Companies 
WHERE 
    Symbol LIKE 'ZY%' OR 
    Name LIKE '%ZY%' 
ORDER BY Symbol ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

Basically I want "ZY" to match (ZNGA, Zynga Inc) before it matches (HALO, Halozyme Therapeuti...).

Obviously the reason for the order is this part of the query:

```
ORDER BY Symbol
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What is the criteria for choosing precedence?

Comment: The query should care more about matching Symbol than the Name.

Comment: Your example doesn't quite work then since Zynga's symbol ZNGA doesn't match your search criteria 'ZY%'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to add it to the Order By clause

```
SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Symbol LIKE 'ZY%' OR Name LIKE '%ZY%' 
ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN Symbol LIKE 'ZY%' THEN 1
        WHEN Name LIKE '%ZY%' THEN 2
        END),
Symbol ASC;
```

Comment: This works, with the exception of one typo. The second WHEN clause should compare Name, not Symbol.

Comment: For the OP, a case statement can be used in join condituions and where clauses as well, this can be used to simulate short circuit evaluations (which is what your title suggests you were interested in).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Symbol LIKE 'ZY%' THEN Symbol ELSE Name END ASC
```